# Variable interval via Flux.create / Flux.switchMap

Tags: java, project-reactor

I need a timer that's variable based on user inpu. Here's the smallest example:

```
Flux.<Integer> create(e -> {
   log.info("create"); // Never gets triggered
   e.next(2); // Sample user input: change to 2 second interval
})
   .switchMap(v -> Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(v)))
   .startWith(Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
   .subscribe(e -> log.info("subscribe: {}", e)); // This works
```

In the above:

- I create a `Flux<Integer>` which should emit things based on the user input (in the above it just emits 2),
- Then based on that a new interval is switched to using `switchMap`
- Starting with the default 1 second interval

The above works below the `switchMap` part, i.e. I see it logging "subscribe: N" every second, but the "create" doesn't get logged and `e.next(2)` is never called either.

Why is this not working? Is there a better solution for this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the JavaDoc, `Flux#startWith` will **prepend** the given sequence.

Since you pass `Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))` as an argument, it will infinitely emit longs every second, and your `Flux.create`-based publisher will never get subscribed.

However, it works if you change it to:

```java
.startWith(Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
```

You may also consider changing the code to:

```java
Flux.<Integer> create(e -> {
   log.info("create");
   e.next(2);
})
   .startWith(1)
   .switchMap(v -> Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(v)))
   .subscribe(e -> log.info("subscribe: {}", e));
```

Here, we use `startWith` right after the `Flux.create` block, and let the `switchMap` handle it as any other signal.

Also, be aware that `switchMap(v -> Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(v)))` reads as:
"Start emitting every N seconds where N is the latest emitted value"

If you need to "delay" it only once, consider using `Mono.delay` here as well.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thanks! Wrt *be aware that switchMap(v -> Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(v))) reads as:
"Start emitting every N seconds where N is the latest emitted value"*, can you clarify what warning exactly did you have in mind?

Comment: I wasn't sure what your code is doing and had a guess that you may want to do a one-off delay instead of changing the rate, hence the heads-up